# Special characters in filenames and paths

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have django app that allows users to enter a query and in response returns a list of documents sorted by their relevance. On clicking the download button the users can download the files. For most cases the option works fine but breaks when the file name or the folder path has special characters (such as - `&`). The download button contains the location of where the file is located. If the path or filename contains a special character, only the string upto the special character is passed to the function in the `views.py` file and hence returns a `FileNotFoundError at ...`.

So how do I ensure that django reads the complete path in cases where there are special characters involved

Comment: Can you add `accept-charset="utf-8"` to your form tag

Comment: @RajaSimon Okay so I omitted a few details to keep the question easy to understand. Once a user enters a query the relevant documents are listed. On clicking the document title, the user is directed to page where they can view the text of the file. Thats where the download link option is available. While rendering the page, I am passing the location of the file(which I am looking up from a database) using the `context` dictionary so apart from the box where the user enters the query there's no `form` element involved

Comment: Oh gotcha! I believe `&` encode is `%26` try that! And decode in your Django server

Comment: @RajaSimon Thats just once case I believe, There could cases with other characters as well. Don't want to go around doing it this way.

Comment: This is the only way I believe. If you want other characters look at [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [urlencode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode)

```
{{link_to_file|urlencode}}
```